# Add new labels on button listener GWT

Tags: gwt, button, label, gxt

I'm trying to add new labels to a panel and this is when a button is clicked, in fact the number of labels is unknowing because my application consists in extracting some informations from a file and then display each information in a label so i have to upload the file and then extract the informations, i created an uploadfile and i'm able to extract the informations but i face a problem to display each information in its label, i can't create many labels and then with label.settext() make each information in its label beacuase the number of labels/informations is variable.

So can you advice/help me so i can make this working.

Best regards.

Comment: Definitely will help you..show your code..your description is somewhat fishy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the result from an `Array` for example you can do like this:

```java
String[] data; //You can add you data here

addButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
             for (String s : data) {
                      RootPanel.get().add(new Label(s));
             }
        }
    });
```

That way you can add as much Labels as you want

Comment: thank you for the answer but i want the add(new label) in the listener of the button so when the button is clicked at once the informations are extracted and displayed

Comment: I have already changed It so the add will be done when you click the addButton

Comment: If that is what you wanted you can accept/validate the question. Else you could ask us if it's not that what you wanted

Comment: with RootPAnel.get() it works but when i changed with the panel which will display the labels it's the same there's nothing

Comment: thank you it appears that the problem is the type of the panel, the panel first was formpanel and when i changed it to absolutepanel it works and all the labels are showing, thank you

Comment: well it's the same thing I can't see why it won't work!
You can for example use a FlowPanel:

`FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
RootPanel.get().add(panel);
addButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
             for (String s : data) {
                      panel.add(new Label(s));
             }
        }
    });`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable number of Labels with a LinkedList.

```
            int count =  x ; //Quantity of labels you need;
    LinkedList<Label> labelList = new LinkedList<Label>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count ;i++)
    {
        Label tmpLabel  = new Label();
        tmpLabel.setText(STUFF) //Here you have to set your content
        labelList.add(tmpLabel);
    }
            // Now we add the Labels to the Panel
             for (int ind = 0; ind < labelList.size() ;ind++)
    {
        panel.add(labelList.get(ind)); //panel is the panel you show
    }
```

If you don't have to access the labels later, you don't need the LinkedList and could add them direct to your panel.
You didnt say how you exactly attach the Labels, but if you use a Grid you have to set the size of it depending on your information.